# SQL Server 2008 Foreign Key error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried inputting my primary and foreign keys after creating my table. However I am having an issue with my foreign key, and would appreciate any help! Here is my code:

```
Create Table EMPLOYEE 
(
    SSN_Number CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    First_Name Varchar(15)NOT NULL,
    Mid_Name Char,
    Last_Name Varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Birthday Date,
    Address Varchar(50),
    Gender Char,
    Salary Money default 8000,
    Supervisor_SSN Char(9),
    Department_Number int
);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_employee PRIMARY KEY (SSN_Number);
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_employee CHECK (Gender IN ('M', 'm', 'F', 'f'))
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_employee FOREIGN KEY (Supervisor_SSN) REFERENCES employee (SSN_Number) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

The error I get for the foreign key is:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_employee' on table 'EMPLOYEE' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: I don't think you can use CASCADE with a self-referencing foreign key. (In fact, I'm not a big fan of using CASCADE ever.) Typically your logic to delete an employee who has subordinates would be written in such a way that *first* it re-assigns those subordinates.

Comment: This is an assignment for school, and the directions specifically ask me to write the reference that way.

Comment: Ok, so then this information must be in your notes or in the class resources in some way, no? Or maybe your instructors don't quite know how SQL Server works? Can you show us your exact homework directions? (Not that we're really supposed to help you with your homework.)

Answer (score 0):

Removing a supervisor should set NULL values to all the rows where this supervisor exists

You can't have ON DELETE CASCADE as complained by SQL Server as it creates cycles.

you need to create the foreign key with out ON DELETE clause

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT 
        fk_employee FOREIGN KEY (Supervisor_SSN) REFERENCES employee (SSN_Number) ;
```

Now you need to think how to set supervisor to NULL up on deletion. you can read about the triggers for this.

The hint is use INSETAD OF DELETE trigger on the table and set NULL value for the deleted supervisor.

you can write the trigger by reading up.